# Blender fails?

Tags: ros, morse, blender

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I don't know why this is happening but I've posted the terminal output below. I'm running Xubuntu 12.04 desktop inside VirtualBox. I've enabled 3D acceleration in the VM settings? Blender tries to start but then the screen just becomes garbled/distorted? Roscore appears to start without any problems. Any ideas or thoughts are greatly appreciated. Also, I apologize in advance if this is the wrong forum for this question but I couldn't find anything similar for blender or morse. Thanks.

mybox@mybox-VirtualBox:~$ morse run ros_example.py

morse 0.5.2

Copyright LAAS-CNRS 2011

AL lib: pulseaudio.c:331: PulseAudio returned minreq > tlength/2; expect break up
connect failed: No such file or directory

ndof: spacenavd not found

AL lib: pulseaudio.c:331: PulseAudio returned minreq > tlength/2; expect break up

OpenGL Warning: No pincher, please call crStateSetCurrentPointers() in your SPU

found bundled python: /home/mybox/builds/blender-2.61-linux-glibc27-i686/2.61/python

read blend: /opt/morse/share/morse/data/morse_default_autorun.blend

IOError: Python file "/home/mybox/ros_example.py" could not be opened: No such file or directory

Detected GL_ARB_texture_env_combine

Detected GL_ARB_texture_cube_map

Detected GL_ARB_multitexture

Detected GL_ARB_shader_objects

Detected GL_ARB_vertex_shader

Detected GL_ARB_fragment_shader

Detected GL_ARB_vertex_program

Detected GL_ARB_depth_texture

Blender Game Engine Started

Error: Not freed memory blocks: 4

VIEW3D_OT_game_start len: 120 0xad9bcfe0

wmOperatorPtrRNA len: 12 0xb6a74fe0

IDProperty group len: 76 0xadae09a0

wmOperatorReportList len: 28 0xb6ce4c60

Blender quit

X Error of failed request:  BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)

Major opcode of failed request:  14 (X_GetGeometry)

Resource id in failed request:  0x3400002

Serial number of failed request:  5731

Current serial number in output stream:  5731

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61669/blender-fails?!?!?/) by [bossdog22](https://answers.ros.org/users/4777/bossdog22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-04-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on 2013-12-23**:
I have the same issue, did you find an answer???

**Comment by [bossdog22](https://answers.ros.org/users/4777/bossdog22/) on 2013-12-23**:
I believe it was a hardware issue. Blender/MORSE didn't like the AMD cpu & ATI video card combo. I run the VM on another machine that has an Intel cpu & an NVIDIA video card without any problem. You can get away with an AMD cpu & an NVIDIA video combo but I haven't seen a whole lot of success with AMD & ATI combos.

**Comment by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on 2013-12-23**:
In the end I had the first error of pulseaudio (PulseAudio returned minreq > tlength/2..........) with an update I needed from the sound driver, I downgraded it afterwards. Anyway, I was doing a new installation in my machine, I had the error with the ros sync, because the simulation without ros seemed to be working well, nevertheless, I need further testing but right now I have it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

Running 3D applications from a virtual machine is generally speaking a bad idea. Even if you get a correct display, performances are likely to be poor.

Based on the error message (`Major opcode of failed request: 14 (X_GetGeometry)`), it looks like the VM 3D driver does not support an OpenGL primitive required by Blender.

Besides, you should update both Ubuntu and MORSE to their latest version (the 3D drivers have improved a lot over the last 2 years).

Last point: we usually recommend MORSE users to use answer.ros.org to ask questions related to MORSE + ROS. For 'MORSE only' questions, it is usually preferable to drop a mail to `morse-users@laas.fr` or to fill a bug on MORSE GitHub repository.

---

Originally posted by [severin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2119/severin/) with karma: 240 on 2013-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1